# nth-everything styling last word with CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I trying to add style to my sample word using CSS and Jquery JS with additional JS from this solution:

```
'http://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/djuIx'
```

I'am able to colorize ODD and EVEN letters, and also nth(n) letter but I have problem with :last-word example. This is what I made and :last-word not works for me :/ [my version](https://codepen.io/magisterson/pen/eWpyYj/)

Comment: Provide a [mcve], please. BTW, I didn't downvote...yet.

Comment: `::last-word` Did you try this?

Comment: yeah i tried this too but no positive result :/

Comment: Your codepen must have an incorrect "nth-everything" plugin. As replacing your code with theirs worked.

Comment: Check this example - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LypQZW.  `Credits:` https://codepen.io/mel/pen/jLEKH?css-preprocessor=none`

Comment: SO has a built-in feature code snippet, use it instead of codepen. If you have to use external online editor, make it be jsbin or jsfiddle, not codepen.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will highlight the last word of `span, div, p` having the class name `highlight_last_word`.

Credits: https://codepen.io/mel/pen/jLEKH?css-preprocessor=none

```js
$(function() {
  $(".highlight_last_word").html(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().trim().split(" ");
    var last = text.pop();
    return text.join(" ") + (text.length > 0 ? " <span class='last-word'>" + last + "</span>" : last);
  });
})
```

```css
.last-word {
  color: #F00;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="highlight_last_word">
  This is sample text to color last WORD
</span><br><br>

<span class="highlight_last_word">
  Some text which could be long enought to move to next line. Some text which could be long enought to move to next line. Some text which could be long enought to move to next line. Some text which could be long enought to move to next line.
</span><br><br>

<span class="highlight_last_word">
  This is some other text
</span>
```